# Twilio - How to identify when user replies with opt-out keyword and unsubscribe them? - Django Python

Tags: django-views, twilio, twilio-api

I would like to unsubscribe a user from sms notifications when they reply with one of twilio's default opt-out keywords: STOP, UNSTOP, UNSUBSCRIBE or CANCEL https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-

And resubscribe the client to my database & sms notifications if they type START, YES and UNSTOP

Is there a special way to do this? - I did not see any good doc from Twilio on how to handle this. Or do I just have to watch for the users to reply through my existing sms webhook and implement something such as the following:

```
def text_message(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        message_body = request.POST['Body']
        if message_body == "STOP" or message_body == "UNSTOP" or message_body == "UNSUBSCRIBE" or message_body == "CANCEL":
            #unsubscribe phone number from my database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, your application needs to incorporate the logic to update the user channel preference in your CRM (so you don't attempt to send another SMS if that user opt-out of that channel). Twilio handles the blacklist for long codes, so if you attempt to send an opt-out party an SMS, Twilio will respond with an error.

Twilio support for opt-out keywords (SMS STOP filtering)
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-

> Any of these STOP keyword replies will prevent a customer from
>   receiving new messages from the Twilio phone number they're responding
>   to. When Twilio receives one of these replies, we will create a
>   "blacklist" entry on our side, and then pass the message on to your
>   webhook. Once we have a blacklist entry for a particular recipient
>   phone number, any future attempts to message them will be met with a
>   400 response from our API, along with Error Code 21610 - Message
>   cannot be sent to the 'To' number because the customer has replied
>   with STOP. Recipients can disable this message stop, and resume
>   receiving messages with the START, YES, or UNSTOP commands as outlined
>   below.

Comment: "Twilio handles the blacklist for long codes" Do you mean for a long phone number? How is it / who handles it for a 5digit marketing number short code>

Comment: Yes, long codes are typical 10 digit phone numbers. For short codes, I recommend the use of Advanced Opt-out, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services, however without Advanced Opt-out enabled, the customer handles the Opt-in/Opt-out/Help logic/responses on their side to their customers.

Comment: What is the payload for the message that Twilio sends to the webhook?